# Magnific Popup - Loading content from external page and put it in the slideshow

Tags: jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

Here is what i want to do. I'm attempting to make the galleries I have on my site more portable so i can generate a link to my projects page and then have Magnific Popup display the contents from that page into the slider.

I'd like to work like it would if all of the elements were on this page maybe hidden inline, but i can't load these items inline, i have to fetch them from the external page.

Let's look at some code, first off, I have a text link that links to the projects page:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/projects/my-project-template/" class="external-media">View Project</a>
```

If you visit the project template, you'll see the carousel of work samples.  But if a link with class .external-media is clicked, jquery should take over and load items from this page into the magnific popup.

I have the data outputting in html format and I also tried json too.  The html structure is something like the following:

```
<div id="gallery">
<a href="photo1.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal"><img src="/thumbnail1.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
<a href="photo2.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal"><img src="/thumbnail2.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
<a href="photo3.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal"><img src="/thumbnail3.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
<a href="photo4.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal"><img src="/thumbnail4.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
</div>
```

Then my javascript looks like this, i was trying to use the ajax type.

```
jQuery('.external-media').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  modal: false,
  gallery: {
    enabled: true,
    navigateByImgClick: true,
    preload: [0,1]
  },
  image: {
    tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
    titleSrc: function(item) {
    return item.el.attr('title');
    }
  },
  callbacks: {
    parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
    mfpResponse.data = jQuery(mfpResponse.data).find('#gallery');
    console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
  },
  ajaxContentAdded: function() {                            
    $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      delegate: 'a',
      gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                tPrev: 'previous',
                tNext: 'next',
                tCounter: '%curr% of %total%'
      },
      image: {
       verticalFit: true,
       titleSrc: function (item) {
       return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="' + item.src + '" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> open original</a>';
          }
        },
    });
    console.log(this.content);
    }
  }
});
```

Right now what happens when i click the text link, it displays all 4 images stacked on top of each in the lightbox.  I want to display one at a time in the slideshow with the left, right arrows.

Basically, have it look exactly like how it does if all of the elements are on  the same page.

Anyone got any tips how i can load images from an external source and populate the lightbox in a slideshow?

===

I'm exploring some other options now since some of you offered some ideas.  Here is what I got, but it doesnt seem to work.  I think it is a half solution right now.  I have a click function that grabs the contents from the permalink page and loads it into a div on the current page template.  I can see the items in the content div after i click the link but i can't get the lightbox to open.  Clearly i am doing something wrong here.

```
$('.external-media').click(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href') + ' #gallery';
    var items = [];

    $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
                         $('#content').html(
                            $(data).find('.slide').each(function() {
                             items.push({
                                 src: $(this)
                                });
                         })
                    );
            }
    });

    $.magnificPopup.open({
        type: 'inline',
        gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                tPrev: 'previous',
                tNext: 'next',
                tCounter: '%curr% of %total%'
        }
    }); // close mpopup

}); // close click
```

Two things i am seeing when i click this function.  I see the items appear in the div, they do not load in the lightbox.  However, clicking one of the items does load that item into the lightbox.  So that is a problem because i want the lightbox to open right when the user clicks the link.

The other issue i see when i click the link i am getting a javascript error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parsed' of undefined
```

I'm going to experiment some more, but if you guys have some other thought i am open to hear any and all options, suggestions.

Comment: Can you put this code up on a fiddle so that folks can better understand the problem?

Comment: umm, I don't see   items:   in you script. http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/zvLny

Comment: i want to add it to a jsfiddle or something, but since i would need to do the call cross domain, the ajax won't work.  Any suggestions to maybe white list the domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer isn't 100% but it is close enough for me to post this as answer.  The remaining issues are just front-end stuff.

With this code I'm able to get the items from the other page to load in the carousel, however, the html markup that wraps around the items is not correct.  I'm still working on that part.  I think this is pretty close that i wanted to share it so others can see how to accomplish a similar thing if they want too.

This is how you would load items from a different page on your site to appear in a lightbox.  It works in the same way as if the items were inline.

First, you need a link that goes to your page that has your items on it and you need to apply the "external-media" class.

```
<a href="{permalink}" class="external-media">External Media Link</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then, I'm using ajax to grab these items from a div with id="gallery".  I'm loading the content into a div with id="content" on the page where the link is.

Here is the jquery click function and the ajax call.  I did need to add the items portion in this part to get the items into the lightbox. (Thanks Emm for that and I will award my bounty to you for that part.)

```
$('.external-media').click(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href') + ' #gallery';
    var items = [];

    $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
              $('#content').html(
                $(data).find('.slide').each(function() {
                  items.push({
                    src: $(this)
                  });
                })
              );
            },
            complete: function() {
              $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: items,
                type: 'inline',
                image: {
                 markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
                 '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                 '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
                 '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
                 '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
                 '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '</div>',
                },
                gallery: { enabled: true }
            }); // close mpopup
         }
    });    
});
```

The last bit is to modify the html code that wraps the items in the lightbox to make it responsive and match the other lightboxes that i have on other parts of the site.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.external-media').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var items = [];
    $.ajax({
            url: jQuery(this).attr('href'),
            type:'GET',
            success: function(data){
                $(data).find('.slide').each(function() {
                    items.push({
                        src: $(this).attr("src"),
                        title: $(this).attr("alt")
                    });
                });
            },
            complete: function() {
              $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: items,
                type: 'image',
                gallery: { enabled: true }
            });
         }
    });    
});
```

Comment: You may want to add a little context to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see items: in your script.

```
 $('.open-gallery-link').click(function() {
 /*an items array that will get passed to the popup*/
 var items = [];
 $( $(this).attr('href') ).find('.slide').each(function() {
   items.push( {
     src: $(this) 
    } );
  });

 $.magnificPopup.open({
   items:items,
   gallery: {
      enabled: true 
    }
  });
});
```

For multiple instances:

```
 $('.first-popup-link, .second-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    closeBtnInside:true
  });
```

[many more examples are here](http://codepen.io/collection/nLcqo/)

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner.  Life events have prevented me from doing so.  Here is the problem.  The gallery of items is not on the same page as the link that opens the gallery.  I tried your click function above and i'm going to continue to work with that, but it doesnt work.  I think this solution works if it is inline...I'll play around with it a little more.

Comment: this doesn't work.  but it did give me an idea, so maybe you can help me work through this...I'm going to update the question...the idea i have is loading the content from the projects page into a div with id="content" onto the current page when the link is clicked.  I can do this with ajax.  I then want the items that are in that content div to open in the lightbox so you can swipe through.  Keep in mind my gallery items are not on the same page as the link.  I'm trying to make it so the link can live anywhere and load the gallery items from another page.

Comment: I've arrived at a almost complete solution.  I had to use ajax to load the page and then use the complete to open the lightbox using the magnificpopup api.  I will post my answer below.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks Emm for your help...stuck on something new now...posting a new question now...

Answer (score 1):

I personally ran into this issue as well but instead of loading all my content from one external page I had to load it from multiple external pages.

The HTML I used

```
    <a href="ajax.html" class="ajax-popup-link">Click me for popup 1</a>
    <a href="ajax-1.html" class="ajax-popup-link">Click me for popup 2</a>
    <a href="ajax-2.html" class="ajax-popup-link">Click me for popup 3</a>
```

Then for the javascript I used the built in methods that Magnific already has.

```
     $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    gallery: {
        // options for gallery
        enabled: true
    },
    ajax: {
        settings: null, // Ajax settings object that will extend default one - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
        // For example:
        // settings: {cache:false, async:false}

        cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur', // CSS class that will be added to body during the loading (adds "progress" cursor)
        tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.' //  Error message, can contain %curr% and %total% tags if gallery is enabled
    },

    callbacks: {
        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            // mfpResponse.data is a "data" object from ajax "success" callback
            // for simple HTML file, it will be just String
            // You may modify it to change contents of the popup
            // For example, to show just #some-element:
            // mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#some-element');

            // mfpResponse.data must be a String or a DOM (jQuery) element

            console.log('Ajax content loaded:', mfpResponse);
        },
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            // Ajax content is loaded and appended to DOM
            console.log(this.content);
        }
    }
});
```

If you needed to parse the HTML before placing it in the popup box you could just go inside the parseAjax and it will only show that fragment in the popup box. I did notice however in my case if I tried to get a fragment of the HTML and not the whole piece the default magnific css would break and my content would not be centered automatically. If I grabbed the whole file and inserted it without parsing the HTML the default magnific css works fine and everything is centered nicely.

```
     callback: {
         parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
             mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#some-element');
         }
     }
```

Comment: Just a comment, instead of using `mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#some-element');` better use  `mfpResponse.data = $($.parseHTML(mfpResponse.data)).filter('#some-element');` because jQuery doesn't have an option to convert raw HTML code of whole page to single jQuery DOM element just via `$()`. see more info [here](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/504)